# How to open page in different tab using ui-router Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular.js `UI-ROUTER` for navigating the page. Here I need to open one page in a new tab of browser. My code is below.

New.html:

```
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
  <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Latitude:</span>
  <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');">
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-if=" latitude">
  <a ui-sref="map" target="_blank">Display Location On The Map</a>
</div>
```

Here until unless the `Latitude` field has no value, the above link `Display Location On The Map` will not display to user but here still the field has no value but its displaying to user. This is one problem. I am providing my routing file below.

```
.state('new', {
      url: '/new',
      templateUrl: 'new.html',
      controller: 'newController'
    })
    .state('map', {
      url: '/map',
      templateUrl: 'map.html',
      controller: 'mapController'
    })
```

Here I need when the user will click on that link (`i.e-Display Location On The Map`) the latitude value will display in map.html file.

map.html:

```
<div id="dvMap" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">{{latitude}}</div>
```

But here when user is clicking on that link the page is not coming. It's giving the following message.

```
Not Found

The requested URL  was not found on this server.
```

Here is my [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/uD8zenLW3UMbnDcbymFg).

Comment: in ng-if only check  !latitude ( ng-if="!latitude") because when you are not entering any value your model is undefined and not empty

Comment: @Chetan : When user is not entering any value the link should not display. So how  `ng-if="!latitude"` will work. I implemented its not working.

Comment: ooh sorry.... just reverse the condition (ng-if = "latitude")

Comment: or try (ng-if = "latitude!=undefined && latitude!=''')

Comment: @Chetan : Yes its right but my major problem is unable to open a new link in different tab. Can you solve this ?

Comment: i dont see parent view(i.e customer) of map state in your routing file

Comment: tell me something.. is it working without _blank target?

Comment: No,its redirecting into new tab but the proper page is not coming.I have already reported the error in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127530/discussion-between-chetan-and-satya).

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!--Change you HTML with below.-->

    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Latitude:</span>
        <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-if="latitude.length > 0">
        <a ui-sref="map" target="_blank">Display Location On The Map</a>
    </div>
```